# trying to subtract a value from my json but it returns nan

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to subtract a value from my json but it returns nan.
Can you tell me how to return as number ?

Providing snippet of code below :

```
console.log("this.state.sportsInfo.thisYear->" + (this.state.sportsInfo.thisYear) - 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the `thisYear` value to the string, and then subtract one:

```
"a string" + 42 - 1
"a string42" - 1
Number("a string42") - 1
NaN - 1
NaN
```

To fix this behavior, simply put the `-1` *inside* of the parantheses:

```
console.log("Value: " + (this.state.sportsInfo.thisYear - 1));
```